# How to Programatically Check if the Location Services is Turned On or Off in browser using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i'm developing a website that use geolocation, but nothing happens if i access it with location service disabled. It should show user alert message to enable location service.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, if geolocation is supported by browser, is check the error code of `getCurrentPosition`

> 1. PERMISSION_DENIED - if the user clicks that “Don’t Share” button or otherwise denies you access to their location.
> 2. POSITION_UNAVAILABLE - if the network is down or the positioning satellites can’t be contacted.
> 3. TIMEOUT - if the network is up but it takes too long to calculate the user’s position. How long is “too long”? I’ll show you how to
>      define that in the next section.

```
if(navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      docode, handle_error)
}

function handle_error(err) {
  if (err.code == 1) {
    // PERMISSION_DENIED 
  }
  else if (err.code == 2) {
    // POSITION_UNAVAILABLE 
  }
  else if (err.code == 3) {
    // TIMEOUT  
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked perfectly but for only the location only when GEO is enabled in browser. What I really  want is check whether the GEO is enabled or not? IF not allow user to turn on the GEO feature to the user.